# reStructuredText: How to remove space after a hyperlink

Tags: hyperlink, restructuredtext

A hyperlink in reStructuredTest looks like this:

```
A hyperlink_ is a reference to a data.

.. _hyperlink: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperlink
```

This works great for languages like English, as each word is clearly separated by a space. However, in some other languages, this may not be always the case. Take Korean for example.

> 하이퍼링크는 ... (apparently [a non-trivial amount of CJK characters are not allowed in StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322508/not-allowed-to-post-because-body-cannot-contain-text/322509), so I'm removing all CJK except for absolutely necessary parts).

Here, '하이퍼링크' is a noun and the tailing character '는' is a [postposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_postpositions). The problem is that if I try to make the word '하이퍼링크' a hyperlink, I'm given two choices.

1. `하이퍼링크_ 는 ...` This produces an output like

   > [하이퍼링크](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperlink) 는 ...

   with an undesired space after the word 'hyperlink'.
2. `하이퍼링크_는 ...` This won't be recognized by the rst compiler as a valid hyperlink.

I would like a hyperlink without a space at the end of it. Is this possible with reStructuredText?

Answer (score 5):

I figured spaces can be escaped with a backslash `\` just like other syntactical components of reStructuredText (such as an underscore `_` or a colon `:`).

```
하이퍼링크_\ 는 자료를 가리킬 수 있는 참조 고리이다.

_하이퍼링크: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperlink
```

This will produce a desired output.

Answer (score 1):

The [character level inline markup](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/config.html#character-level-inline-markup) option in docutils 0.13+ can help. With this option enabled you can write `하이퍼링크_는` and it can recognize it as valid hyperlink, but you have to add the following switch when compiling:

```
python rst2html.py --character-level-inline-markup 1.rst > 1.html
```

Note however it might mess up if your hyperlink contains underscores. So use with care.